# How to use a variable that resets in every folder to batch-rename files?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to rename some .png files in a lot of folders with the folder name and an increasing index, that resets in every folder.

My script doesn't work and I think that the issue is with the index resetting, can someone help me?

Note that in the folders there are some files (with a different estension, like .pdf or .log) that I don't want to rename.

Here my best attempt.

```
    @echo off

setlocal
rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (
   
        rem crafting the string: the variable resets in every subfolder
        for /R %%X in (*.png) do (
            if not "%%~dpX"=="!LASTPATH!" (set /A num=0) else (set /A num=!num!+1)
            set LASTPATH=%%~dpX
            ren "%%X" "!%%A%_%num%!.png"

    )
)
```

Edit:

Here the script edited following the tips in the comments.

```
    @echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (
        set num=0
    
        rem crafting the string: the variable resets in every subfolder
    for /R %%X in (*.png) do (
            set /a num+=1 && ren "%%X" "%%~nA_!num!%%~xA"

    )
)
```

It renames the file but the index doesn't resets and the files doesn't have the right extension.

Edit:
Using `"%%~nA_!num!.png"` instead of @stephan suggestion, it rename them with the correct extension.

The files are renamed like this: firstfoldername_1 firstfoldername_2 firstfoldername_n with n is the number of files of the first folder. Then in the second folder the files are named with the first folder name and with a progressive index, like n+1, so it doesn't reset the index nor change the folder name.

Comment: Numerous problems, you have not `enabledelayedexpansion`. You have also not set the variables correctly. What is happening here, `!%%A%_%num%`?

Comment: why not simply `set num=0` into the empty line between the two `for` loops? You can increase a variable with `set /a num+=1`. And what do you think `"!%%A%_%num%.png` is doing?

Comment: I think that "!%%A%_%num%!.png" is the newname of the file (sorry for the typos), where %%A% is the folder name and %num% is the index.

Comment: the folder name is `%%A` and the counter is (or better should be) `!num!`, which leads to `"%%~nA_!num!%%~xA"`. See the "modifiers" section of `for /?` for details.

Comment: I see, but why the `%%~xA`? Doesn't it takes the folder extension?

Comment: `for /R %%X in (*.png) do (` should surely read `for /R "%%A" %%X in (*.png) do (`, otherwise, I don't really see the point of iterating each folder in the current directory.

Comment: I understand how the modifiers function, my question is: why i need the `!num!%%~xA`? Doesn't I need to use the extension of the file? The script now changes the file name correctly but with the wrong extension.

Comment: Concerning your second approach: you reset the index number before iterating a directory tree; you could use `for /R %%I in (.) do (set "num=0" & for %%J in ("%%~I\*.png) do (set /A "num+=1" & ren "%%~J" "%%~dpnJ_!num!%%~xJ")`, or even better (to avoid double-renaming), `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('echo .^& dir /S /B /A:D') do (set "num=0" & for %%J in ("%%I\*.png") do (set /A "num+=1" & ren "%%~J" "%%~dpnJ_!num!%%~xJ")` (both variants first enumerate the directory tree, resets the index number and then iterates over the `*.png` files per (sub-)directory)…

Comment: I'd suggest that the `ren "%%X" "%%~nA_!num!%%~xA"` should be `ren "%%X" "%%~nX_!num!%%~xX"` because as written,it should rename to `(name of directory)_(serialnumber)(extension of directory)`. Personally, I'd also change all `%%X` references to something like `%%E` to avoid confusion between metavariablename and modifier. From what I see here, it should then work, so some expansion of what it actually does compared with what it is expected to do would be helpful.

Comment: @Magoo I edited the post showing the problems.

Comment: `for /R %%X in (*.png) do (` should be `for /R %%X in (".\%%A\*.png") do (` otherwise the `for /r` is executed on the current directory for each directoryname found by the `for/d`instead of on the subtree `%%A`. And I insist that `%%~xA` should be `%%~xX`

Comment: Yes as I said in a comment `%%~xA` was wrong and I changed it to `.png` that's the same as what you have written. Now with ` (".\%%A\*.png") ` it goes correctly, it you want   to write an answer I can vote it.

Comment: `I see, but why the %%~xA? Doesn't it takes the folder extension?` Yes - my fault.  It should be `%%~xX` of course. Sorry for the confusion.